# Boo: is the following code possible

Tags: dsl, boo

Is there a situation when the following is a valid Boo statement:

```
target "something" requires "something"
```

where `target` and `requires` can be a macros/method/anything other (except for keywords)?
This is a DSL question, so any language hack will do as long as it compiles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a patch to support this, but by default, no.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a link to the patch? Not sure what words to Google for it.